# Can't select command field which type is memo

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I'm working on a crystal report and I want to insert a pie chart that shows percentages. I have a view that contains the field that I'm interested in : Descr(descrtiption) (NVARCHAR), I successfully added a command that gets the number of occurences of each Description. The problem is that when I try to add that field to the chart I can't see it,

here is the query that gets the values

[image]

here is the chart expert window I get

[image]

and as you can see the field is not checked in the field explorer

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to shorten the `memo` field to be able to use it in this manner.  Try:

```
CAST(Desc AS NVARCHAR(2000))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Having clause instead of where condition in query.

```
Select count(*) as NBoccurrence,descr 
From tbl_nm
Group by descr 
Having your condition
```

Comment: even with this change I still can't see it